Cargo build on workspace rebuilds some crates when run
I've run into an issue where with a virtual workspace with multiple binary targets, cargo build completes, and then when running some of the binary targets needs to rebuild some of the dependencies, and some of the final binaries.  I have the proxy binary as the default-run key for this.
The final "bit" of compiling and running is the following:
username@DEV:cargo-demo$ cargo build
... SNIP ...
   Compiling dxr v0.6.2
   Compiling dxr_server v0.6.2
   Compiling server v0.1.0 (/mnt/nfshome/username@DEV/Repos/Rust/cargo-demo/server)
   Compiling proxy v0.1.0 (/mnt/nfshome/username@DEV/Repos/Rust/cargo-demo/proxy)
   Compiling client v0.1.0 (/mnt/nfshome/username@DEV/Repos/Rust/cargo-demo/client)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 44.30s
username@DEV:cargo-demo$ cargo run
   Compiling once_cell v1.19.0
   Compiling log v0.4.21
   Compiling dircpy v0.3.16
   Compiling cc v1.0.95
   Compiling zeromq-src v0.2.6+4.3.4
   Compiling zmq-sys v0.12.0
   Compiling zmq v0.10.0
   Compiling proxy v0.1.0 (/mnt/nfshome/username@DEV/Repos/Rust/cargo-demo/proxy)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 25.65s
     Running `target/debug/proxy`
^C
username@DEV:cargo-demo$ 

So after successful "cargo build" at the workspace level, "cargo run" still causes my target to build.  Note that when I run cargo run --bin server there is no rebuild.  That works.  But the client needs a rebuild too.  And after I've run all 3 binaries, I can run them all without rebuild... until the next change of course.
What I've got is I was trying out some ZeroMQ (the code below is extremely close to their examples, because that's what they're from), and then pairing it with dxr for some proof-of-concept stuff.  I have it down to pretty simple for minimization purposes:
/
  Cargo.toml
  Cargo.lock // Generated
  client/
    Cargo.toml
    src/
      main.rs
  proxy/
    Cargo.toml
    src/
      main.rs
  server/
    Cargo.toml
    src/
      main.rs

The workspace-level Cargo.toml is this:
[workspace]
members = [ "client", "proxy", "server"]
resolver = "2"

[workspace.package]
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[workspace.dependencies]

The client's Cargo.toml is:
[package]
name = "client"
version.workspace = true
edition.workspace = true

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
zmq = "0.10.0"

client code:
use std::error::Error;

fn stringify(x: Vec<u8>) -> String {
    format!("Failed string decode from bytes: {x:?}")
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let context = zmq::Context::new();
    let subscriber = context.socket(zmq::SUB)?;
    subscriber.set_rcvtimeo(3000)?;
    subscriber.set_linger(0)?;
    subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5560")?;
    println!("Connected");
    subscriber.set_subscribe(b"B")?;
    subscriber.set_subscribe(b"C")?;

    loop {
        println!("Trying to receive the string");
        let address = subscriber.recv_string(0)?.map_err(stringify)?;
        let contents = subscriber.recv_string(0)?.map_err(stringify)?;
        println!("[{}] {}", address, contents);
    }
    // Ok(()) would be necessary if loop was broken out of, but since it can't except through return or error, we're good
}

proxy's Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "proxy"
version.workspace = true
edition.workspace = true
default-run = "proxy"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
zmq = "0.10.0"

proxy code:
use std::error::Error;


fn main()  -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let context = zmq::Context::new();

    let mut frontend = context.socket(zmq::XSUB)?;
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5559")?;

    let mut backend = context.socket(zmq::XPUB)?;
    backend.bind("tcp://*:5560")?;

    let mut control = context.socket(zmq::PULL)?;
    control.bind("tcp://*:5561")?;

    zmq::proxy_steerable(&mut frontend, &mut backend, &mut control)?;
    Ok(())
}

And the server's, which has some dxr dependencies in it:
[package]
name = "server"
version.workspace = true
edition.workspace = true

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
dxr = { version = "0.6.2", features = ["derive", "multicall", "i8", "nil"]}
chrono = { version = "0.4.19", features = ["clock"], default-features = false }
tokio = { version = "1.14", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread", "signal", "time"] }
dxr_server = { version="0.6.2", features = ["multicall", "axum"] }
zmq = "0.10.0"

server code:
use std::{
    error::Error,
    sync::{atomic::AtomicBool, Arc},
    thread, time,
};


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let running = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(true));

    let ctrl_c_handler_cpy = Arc::clone(&running);
    let handler = tokio::spawn(async move {
        tokio::signal::ctrl_c().await.unwrap();
        println!("Got the Ctrl-C signal to shutdown");
        ctrl_c_handler_cpy.store(false, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed);
    });

    let zmq_running_cpy = Arc::clone(&running);
    let zmq_handler = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        println!(
            "Return from zmq_test is: {:?}",
            zmq_test(zmq_running_cpy)
        );
    });

    println!("Starting server");
    let _ = tokio::join!(handler, zmq_handler);
    Ok(())
}

fn zmq_test(
    running: Arc<AtomicBool>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let context = zmq::Context::new();
    let publisher = context.socket(zmq::PUB)?;
    publisher.connect("tcp://localhost:5559")?;

    // Loop while "running" boolean is true
    let mut iteration: u64 = 0;
    while running.load(std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed) {
        publisher.send_multipart(["A", &format!("We don't want to see this - {iteration}")], 0)?;
        println!("Sent A - {iteration}");
        publisher.send_multipart(["B", &format!("We would like to see this - {iteration}")], 0)?;
        println!("Sent B - {iteration}");

        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(2));
        iteration += 1;
    }

    // Now shut down the proxy too
    println!("Shutting down the proxy as well");
    let proxy_control = context.socket(zmq::PUSH)?;
    proxy_control.connect("tcp://localhost:5561")?;
    proxy_control.send("TERMINATE", 0)?;
    Ok(())
}

Note: I only have ZMQ code and tokio in here at this time.  I am running off of dxr's examples (which I've tried separately), but dxr isn't imported/used at all in the example above, it's just in the dependencies.  And this does not happen without dxr_server as a dependency.  chrono and tokio and even dxr itself don't cause this behavior, but add dxr_server, and things go all pear-shaped.
I also tried (and it was originally this way) having some of the dependencies in the workspace, but I broke it all into "3 independent crates" here, and I have this problem.
Any way for it to all get "really compiled" before cargo build finishes without rebuilding when I want to run something?  Is this a problem with dxr, and if so, what is it so I can file the bug (and/or fix it myself) correctly?

I think you've hit https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4463

Thanks @eggyal - so what now?  I guess I'll try cargo-hakari and see if that "just works" for me, but I'm saddened that this is necessary, if it will even work.

hakari doesn't solve this.  cargo-hack does through building everything one at a time, and so at least at the end of the process, it "works" though it still will need to rebuild dependencies depending on what binary I want to rebuild next.  But that's better than nothing.
If anybody has a better suggestion, I'm open to ideas.  Then you can get credit for posting an answer!  I hate self-answering though.  I will, but I'd rather have a better solution.
